# Installing gdm-multiseat on Oracle Linux 6.4

Tags: oracle-linux

I am installing SunRay on Oracle Linux 6 update 4.  Running `utpkgcheck` shows that I don't have gdm-multiseat installed.  However, I don't see it anywhere in the repos I have.  How can I install gdm-multiseat?

I tried `yum search multiseat` and it didn't return any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `/etc/yum.repos.d/public-yum-ol6.repo`

```
[ol6_gdm_multiseat]
name=Oracle Linux 6 GDM Multiseat ($basearch)
baseurl=http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL6/gdm_multiseat/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

Then you can install using `yum install gdm-multiseat`